# I want to assign numbers to rows of data and filter by summing those numbers

Tags: if-statement, dax, multiple-columns, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have multiple tables and each table contains names of staff and answers to different appraisal questions. When staff has answered any appraisal question, an appraisal date is entered in the table. What i want to do using DAX is to look at each table, assign 1 to each row of data with appraisal date and 0 when there isn't an appraisal then. Then i want to look at all the tables and assign 1 if staff has an appraisal date in each table and 0 if all appraisal questions hasn't been answered.

Measure 2 =

VAR counting = IF(VALUES('Appraisal Review'[Appraisal Date]) > 1, 1, 0)

VAR AspirationCount = IF(VALUES('Grid Aspiration Report'[Appraisal Date]) > 1, 1, 0)

VAR CurrentCount = IF(VALUES('Grid Current Report'[Appraisal Date]) > 1, 1, 0)

VAR ObjCount = IF(VALUES('Obj Report'[Appraisal Date]) > 1, 1, 0)

VAR PdpCount = IF(VALUES('PDP'[Appraisal Date]) > 1, 1, 0)

RETURN
IF(counting + AspirationCount + CurrentCount + ObjCount + PdpCount  = 5, 1, 0)

This didn't work and the i edited it and replaced the formula after RETURN with the formular below.

CALCULATE(COUNT(Employee[Employee ID]), FILTER(Employee, counting = 1 && AspirationCount =1

&& CurrentCount = 1 && ObjCount = 1 && PdpCount = 1))

It still didn't work. I am new to DAX so now i'm completely stuck

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only a value in the appraisaldate column if the appraisal has taken place, you can use IF(NOTBLANK(appraisaldate),1,0) in each of those variables.